# Tried import deployed contract but Identifier not found or not unique

Tags: solidity, remix

I deployed VrfTest contract and imported it. But remix keeps saying below error. Did I do the wrong way to import? VrfTest contract is in the same folder in remix.

```
DeclarationError: Identifier not found or not unique.
  --> contracts/SampleERC721.sol:21:5:
   |
21 |     VrfTest public vrfContract;
   |     ^^^^^^^
```

```js
import "./VrfTest.sol";


contract BullBear is ERC721, ERC721Enumerable, ERC721URIStorage, Ownable, KeeperCompatibleInterface {
    
    VrfTest public vrfContract;

    constructor(uint updateInterval, address _priceFeed, VrfTest _addrVrfContract) ERC721("Bull&Bear", "BBTK") {
        vrfContract = _addrVrfContract;

    }
```

Comment: Is there a contract named `VrfTest` in the `VrfTest.sol` file that you are importing and is the `VrfTest.sol` file in the same directory as your `BullBear` contract?

Comment: `VrtTest.sol` file is in the same directory with `BullBear` contract but I realized that contract name wasn't `VrfTest` in the `VrfTest.sol`. Thank you so much :)

Answer (score 0):

When importing a `.sol` file, we are importing everything declared in it, even multiple contracts, libraries, etc.

If the `.sol` file does not contain a contract with the name of the file, we cannot try to use the contract inside that `.sol` file with the name of the `.sol` file. We need to either change the name of the contract inside the `.sol` file to be the same name as the file or use the correct name of the contract while importing.

You can also use this syntax to import specific things by changing their name if needed to avoid collision with other import names, and import a set of the things declared in the `.sol` file and not everything:

```js
import {VrfTest as VrfTest2, add as func, Point} from "./Foo.sol";
```